# Question about the Smallest Grammar problem.

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar

Is the problem to prove whether or not there exists an algorithm with running time polynomial in the length of the input string $|s|$, or polynomial both in $|s|$ *and* the size of the alphabet $|A|$ ?  The papers I'm looking at assume that you know which one they mean.

**Edit**:
[Paper](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~michaelm/E210/SmallestGrammar.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first sentence of the paper defines what problem they are considering:

> This paper addresses the smallest grammar problem; namely, what is the smallest context-free grammar that generates exactly one given string?

Comment: The problem they also deal with is whether an algorithm in P exists that finds a smallest grammar.  I would be assuming that they mean treating the alphabet size as a constant.  It seems like a reasonable assumption, since when we want the smallest grammar of something, we usually fix the alphabet.  But I'm still not 100% convinced they mean that.

Comment: Well, the alphabet can trivially be taken to be the set of symbols found in the input string, or you could fix it as $\{0,1\}$. I assume that one would allow any number of nonterminals in the grammar; more than $|s|$ of them will never be optimal anyway.

Comment: That's right.   I knew that, but the thought bubbled up again, and I need to think before I shoot questions to the forums.  If an algorithm is bounded by a polynomial in the alphabet size of s, then it is also bounded polynomially in the size of s.